# : bad substitution error writing JSON to file in bash script

Tags: bash, macos

my bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

cat <<EOF > config.json
{
    "host": "READER",
    "server-url": "${server.url}",
    "port": 8080,
}
EOF
```

when I run the file via `./generateJson.sh` or `bash generateJson.sh` then I get the error

```
line 5: ..... : bad substitution
```

I have set the local variable server.url. 
if I run `echo $server.url` in the same terminal session it has a string assigned.

what does the bad substitution error mean?
why is this happening?

I have seen many posts saying to use `#!/bin/bash` or other ways of making sure that it is running on bash not dash. But this makes no difference.

Comment: both have a value when i run echo $server.url and echo ${server.url}.
same error still persists

Comment: @axiac this is a very simple case where a script is appropriate. I am also trying to advance by bash skills

Comment: "I have set the local variable server.url". No, you haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in `bash` (or `/bin/sh`) can not contain dots in their names.  This means that `${server.url}` can not be expanded, and since it does not correspond to a know parameter substitution syntax, the shell complains with the error that you see.

Choose another name for your variable, e.g. `server_url`.

If your variable is actually called `server` and you want to add `.url` to its value, use `$server.url` in the here-document.

If you want to insert the literal string `${server.url}` in the document, then either escape the `$` as `\$`, or use `'EOF'` or `\EOF` to quote the whole here-document (only at the start, not at the end).

Comment: the . in server.url what the problem. Didn't realise that was not possible.